# Type Error (invalid arg type) thrown during npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run `npm start` I get this error. I'm trying to start iquidus block explorer. What can be the problem here? I'm using the latest version of Node.js.

```
internal/fs/utils.js:658
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type number (20867)
    at Object.writeFile (fs.js:1356:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/explorer/bin/cluster:5:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! explorer@1.7.3 start: `node --stack-size=10000 ./bin/cluster`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the explorer@1.7.3 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-17T12_19_42_800Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, issue was in Nodejs version 14.x is not stable so used 12.x version and worked...

Comment: This issue was fixed recently so you can use node.js 14.x with iquidus now: [https://github.com/iquidus/explorer/commit/ee2a273fb4f84a4f3c4014847837f10afb692418](https://github.com/iquidus/explorer/commit/ee2a273fb4f84a4f3c4014847837f10afb692418)